# How to analyze slow program in some computers but not others

Tags: windows-7, windows, debug

I've generated an exe file, using py2exe to pack all the dll needed, and it works flawlessly on my laptop and workstation.
I've tested my program on several computers (same model as my laptop and workstation but with different users and installed programs) sometimes the videos on my program runs slow (I use vlc in order to play the videos inside my program, and even if they run slow on my program they run well on vlc outside my program).

Both computers have resources to spare, the laptop is a Zbook from HP, 8 cores and 16Gb of RAM, and the workstation is a Z840, 32 cores and 130Gb RAM, so I'm guessing it's something related to the dll.

I've used Process Explorer in order to see what dll is using on runtime and it seems to use different dll on different computers, is this behaviour normal?

For example, the offending machine is the only one that uses detoured.dll, msctf.dll.mui, nvd3d9wrap.dll, nvd3dum.dll and nvdxgiwrap.dll

I'm really groping in the dark here, so any help would be apreciated, either something I should be looking for that could be causing this behaviour or some program to debug the exe in the hopes I find something.

Answer (score 0):

The following DLLs don't seem to be problematic :

- **msctf.dll** - belongs to the [Text Services Framework (TSF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Services_Framework)
- **detoured.dll** - part of an Microsoft Research technology named
  [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fdetours%2F)
  which establishes hooks into every application launched on Windows!

Detoured.dll can be disabled via regedit by deleting it from the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs`.

The DLLs named "nv*" are more serious candidates for slow video,
as they belong to Nvidia.
You may update them via the
[NVIDIA Driver Downloads page](http://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx)
either by specifying the video card or running auto-detection via the
GRAPHICS DRIVERS button.

Comment: Updating the drivers, has getting rid of detoured.dll but the program on my laptop is consuming a 12% of the CPU and on the other laptop (same hw) is using up to 60% of the CPU...which I don't understand how or why...

Comment: I think that VLC incorporated into your program is set to use the CPU for rendering rather than the GPU (of which you have two). This maybe can be set in the NVIDIA Control Panel or elsewhere in your Windows.